# apa style-like citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

In my thesis I have to cite the references in the style shown in the picture.
I think it is more near to apa style, but not exactly same. Could anyone please guide how can I generate references in this format. I am using .bib file and working on overleaf.[image]

Comment: What you show does not look a lot like APA style: APA style is an author-year style with author-year citations, yours is a numerical style. You may want to try one of the standard `natbib` styles like `plainnat` for starters if you use `\bibliographystyle`. If you actually use `biblatex` as suggested by the tags, you could start with `style=numeric,` but you will need modifications. Start with https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864.

Answer (score 0):

Try the IEEE style:

```latex
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

It's quite similar, for example:

```latex
[65] S. Xie, R. B. Girshick, P. Dollár, Z. Tu, and K. He, “Aggregated residual transformations for deep neural networks,”
in 2017 IEEE Conference on Computer Vision and Pattern Recognition, CVPR 2017, Honolulu, HI, USA, July
21-26, 2017, pp. 5987–5995, IEEE Computer Society, 2017.
```

For styles have a look [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Biblatex_citation_styles).

Comment: thanks but this way i am loosing alphabetical order. how can I fix it?

Comment: also i don't want inverted commas around the titles of the articles. is there any way i can omit the commas?